# Oracle - FORMAT JSON gives ORA-00932

Tags: sql, json, oracle, select, oracle19c

Why does this code:

```sql
 select
    json_object(
           'name' value name
         FORMAT JSON)
  from users
```

Gives me the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 25
```

If I remove the `FORMAT JSON` it works, but having the `FORMAT JSON` seems to be OK according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A).

I'm on Oracle 19c

What I want to do is return a JSON from an API, it's currently returning as a string, so it's quoted like this `"{"name": "mike"}"` and I want it like `{"name": "mike"}`.

Comment: Something is fishy. Your `value` doesn't seem to be a simple `name` like `'mike'`. `FORMAT JSON` will assume the name is already quoted, so it will not add double-quotes **around `mike`**, it has nothing to do with adding them around the braces surrounding the JSON object. It looks more like you are passing JSON objects as `value` in your call to `JSON_OBJECT`.

Comment: What is the datatype of the name?

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot `name` is a VARCHAR2.

Comment: @mathguy Hmmm, I see, so I should only use `FORMAT JSON` if `name` is a JSON itself?

Comment: select
    json_object(
           'name' value last_name FORMAT JSON)
  from EMPLOYEES; - This works for me, last_name is Varchar2 from the employees table. It's giving output without quotes.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot It doesn't work here. For some reason anything I try doesn't work while I have the `FORMAT JSON`.

Comment: @user5507535 What is your oracle DB version?

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot It's on the question. Oracle 19c

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was mentioned. I am using 18c but do not have your API so can't tell.well, there is no JSON datatype in oracle, JSON data is stored in CLOB or VARCHAR, try transforming your JSON from the front end. In oracle, it is going to be treated as string only.